# Publish questions only after First Posts review

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, questions, new-users

I have been reading Sara Chipp's recent [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/18/building-community-inclusivity-stack-overflow/) which explained how new users in Stack Overflow are afraid of being judged by multiple people. I think that multiple people telling you how your question is wrong, makes the site seem unfriendly.

**My Idea**

Why not hide questions from new users until the question passes through a review in First Posts? That is, until a user reviews the question and marks it as "I'm done" or "No Action Needed", the question will not be viewable to the public.

**What it achieves**

Since a new user's question will be reviewed by only one person initially, it will be easier for the user to respond/edit without being afraid of being judged in public. It will also give more time to respond / edit before getting downvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This system exists more or less (on Stack Overflow at least); it's called the [Triage review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278380/4751173). It gets fed by questions deemed low quality by the system and/or the users; those questions are hidden from the homepage (though not from the other question lists or search). Together with the Help & Improvement queue, its aim is to improve question quality for new users. Here's a nice flowchart I borrowed from Shog's post I linked to:

> [image: flowchart for questions]

The fact that five years later it isn't rolled out to other sites in the network should say enough: it isn't successful enough. Newer projects have started ([Mentoring](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353845/4751173) and the [Ask Question Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381671/4751173)), and the latter seems to have enough potential even outside Stack Overflow.

Comment: So questions in Triage queue are not visible to public?

Comment: *those questions are hidden from the homepage (though not from the other question lists or search)*

Comment: Oh. I was aware of Triage but didn't know that questions were hidden from Homepage. Thank you. I'll accept this answer.

Comment: probably worth noting that triage development which has been silently [aborted midway](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368875/should-very-low-quality-flags-be-offloaded-entirely-to-tag-experts/374490#comment632724_374490): "Triage was predicated on us rewriting all of the views. Which... Very nearly happened. And then didn't..."