# A Modest Proposal for Making a More Civil Community

Tags: feature-request, new-users

Stack Exchange constantly encourages people to be more civil to the new users.  People sign up to a new account on Stack Overflow, ask for someone to solve their homework questions, and get upset if an answer is terse or a moderator closes the question.   So, a modest proposal:

**Provide a setting to ignore new users**

That's it.  If you are person who cannot deal with fourteenth question about "How to convert these Roman numerals to Hex?", just block all questions by reputations under twenty.  Suddenly, most of the questions of "There is an error somewhere.  Here is all my code pasted without formatting" and "I tried this and it does not work".  Poof!  Gone.  You get questions like "Why does my Python context manager swallow exceptions?" instead.

Before everyone piles on with the negative comments, the real question is:

**Why is proposing this sacrilege?**

Comment: That presumes tho that new users have no value at all

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331089/publish-questions-only-after-first-posts-review

Comment: Yes, totally ignore the new users that post junk, thereby increasing the amount of junk that new users see and have to deal with, while ignoring the new users that post gold, thereby reducing the amount of rep they can earn. This is a terrible idea with no connection to how Stack Exchange needs to work or its purpose.

Comment: "I only wish to help users who have already proven they are awesome. Everyone else, well, good luck to them."

Comment: I think that the *real* question has been answered, the real solution is to simply educate new users about what is expected; and how to improve their questions. Ignoring a problem doesn't make it go away, by providing help for those that need it, both with their questions and social skills, we can have an improvement instead of a pit of disparity.

Comment: Related: ["_Does SO need social networking features to improve the experience for expert users?_"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106717/997587)

Comment: 1. Questions from low-rep users still require curation. Hence why I'd want to see them - retag, edit, vote on. 2. Related but the vast majority of spam comes from brand new accounts. Hence, deliberately turning a blind eye to all of them, also means ignoring spam *instead of* handling it correctly. 3. Terrible questions are actually asked by users of all rep levels. Blocking just the lowest reputation ones doesn't really solve the problem in that case.

Answer (score 14):

This proposal sounds like it's designed not for civility nor to be more welcoming, but rather to spare established users the "burden" of dealing with newer members of the community. Like crossing the street to pretend a busker doesn't exist. Which is totally everyone's prerogative, but not if you're relying on that busker to contribute a portion of their revenue to removing graffiti from your street.

Summarizing from the comments:

- If *all* established users can ignore *all* new users, who can possibly ever upvote new users? Similarly, who will be there to guide new users and make them better? Other new users? When will they ever be able to grace established users with their existence?
- A reputation threshold has little correlation with question quality (and can be reached without ever asking a question, never mind a good one). We all know a user with loads of rep who continues asking low quality questions or duplicates they were too lazy to find through a search.
- This would lump all new users into the same "not worthy" bucket, whether their first posts are amazing or utter garbage. And
  again, how would you ever see their amazing first posts, or help
  steer them toward correcting garbage?

The [Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/staging-ground) is a much more constructive initiative that is designed to improve question quality without treating new users like a stigma.

So I would say, **no, this is a bad idea.** And it has nothing to do with being "sacrilege."

If you search, there are [Greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) scripts that can ignore specific users or groups of users; I'm sure it could be tweaked to ignore users < { x } rep (maybe it already has). That is probably a better route for you individually, if that's what you really want; I can't really condone that as native functionality on the site.

Answer (score 4):

> Provide a setting to ignore new users

I feel like that's a little elitist - It also means you miss such gems as - the actual John [Carmack](https://superuser.com/questions/419070/transatlantic-ping-faster-than-sending-a-pixel-to-the-screen) answering a question

It also preassumes *every* new user doesn't know how to ask a good question or somehow having reputation makes you have the ability to *always* post appropriately.

> That's it. If you are person who cannot deal with fourteenth question about "How to convert these Roman numerals to Hex?", just block all questions by reputations under twenty. Suddenly, most of the questions of "There is an error somewhere. Here is all my code pasted without formatting" and "I tried this and it does not work". Poof! Gone. You get questions like "Why does my Python context manager swallow exceptions?" instead.

I have somewhat over 100 reputation on Stack Overflow, despite having somewhere about the programming aptitude of a toddler. You'll likely want to block the association bonus as well. You'd need to sort out the page you see - which means more different queries, which might be inefficient, and I suspect that these things might be heavily cached.

Or you could look at the titles, see what interests you and focus on that. If it's a new question - the front page also shows the reputation of the poster (this changes with actions on the post I guess), so you can eyeball what's worth looking at.

As such this proposal... doesn't actually solve anything. It adds complexity to things without trying to actually resolve any problem, except putting new users in the room under the stairs, to be neither seen not heard.